# Create Database Oracle

Tags: oracle10g

I'm new to oracle. And I'm kind of amused how complicated is to create a database in ORA. It seems that I have to follow all the steps bellow just to create a database. Is there an easier way (without an IDE)?

FROM (http://www.dba-oracle.com/oracle_create_database.htm):

EXTREMELY minimal manual Oracle database creation script

1. Set your ORACLE_SID

export ORACLE_SID=test

export ORACLE_HOME=/path/to/oracle/home

1. Create a minimal init.ora

## $ORACLE_HOME/dbs/init.ora

control_files = (/path/to/control1.ctl,/path/to/control2.ctl,/path/to/control3.ctl)
undo_management = AUTO
undo_tablespace = UNDOTBS1
db_name = test
db_block_size = 8192
sga_max_size = 1073741824 #one gig
sga_target = 1073741824 #one gig

1. Create a password file

$ORACLE_HOME/bin/orapwd file=$ORACLE_HOME/dbs/pwd.ora password=oracle entries=5

1. Start the instance

sqlplus / as sysdba

startup nomount

1. Create the database

create database test
logfile group 1 ('/path/to/redo1.log') size 100M,
            group 2 ('/path/to/redo2.log') size 100M,
            group 3 ('/path/to/redo3.log') size 100M
character set WE8ISO8859P1
national character set utf8
datafile '/path/to/system.dbf' size 500M autoextend on next 10M maxsize unlimited extent management local
sysaux datafile '/path/to/sysaux.dbf' size 100M autoextend on next 10M maxsize unlimited
undo tablespace undotbs1 datafile '/path/to/undotbs1.dbf' size 100M
default temporary tablespace temp tempfile '/path/to/temp01.dbf' size 100M;

Note: there's some other things you can do here, like "ARCHIVELOG" "SET TIME_ZONE =" and "USER SYS IDENTIFIED BY password" and "USER SYSTEM IDENTIFIED BY password"

1. Run catalog and catproc

@?/rdbms/admin/catalog.sql

@?/rdbms/admin/catproc.sql

1. Change passwords

alter user sys identified by whatever;

alter user system identified by whatever;

Comment: Simply install Oracle and let it create database during installation process.

Comment: This isn't a programming question and belongs on ServerFault http://serverfault.com